# Bigquery - Format element syntax for dd mmm yyyy hh:mm

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I've got a string field with the format 'dd mmm yyyy hh:mm', so for example '16 Apr 2020 19:07'.

I'm trying to convert this to a date format using PARSE_DATE but i'm not having any success:

`PARSE_DATE('%d %mm %Y',Created') as Created`

any ideas?

best wishes

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT DATE(PARSE_DATETIME('%d %b %Y %H:%M',Created)) AS Created
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you once again Mikhail!!